# How to use command lines to install GD library for Drupal on Linux?

Tags: linux, drupal, command-line, gd, putty

What is the command line for installing GD library for drupal on Linux in PuTTY?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ubuntu or debian based:

`apt-get install php5-gd`